# Prove with combinatorial arguments this equation

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, natural-numbers, combinatorial-proofs

Prove with combinatorial arguments, that, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} =0$$

Comment: What have you tried ? When asking a question always remember : __Provide details. Share your research.__

Comment: that's perfect =D

Comment: Those answers didn't help. If anyone could make another try with more basic resources it'd help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mathematical induction, we have:

$$n = 1\,\, \to \,\,\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\0 \end{array}} \right) - \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\ 1 \end{array}} \right) = 1 - 1 = 0$$

Now we must show that if 
$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\k \end{array}} \right)}  = 0$$
then
$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n + 1} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{n + 1}\\k \end{array}} \right)}  = 0$$

Using the [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)
$$
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{n + 1}\\k\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\k\end{array}} \right) + \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\{k - 1}\end{array}} \right)
$$
we have,
$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n + 1} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{n + 1}\\k\end{array}} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n + 1} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\k\end{array}} \right)}  + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n + 1} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\{k - 1}\end{array}} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\k\end{array}} \right)}  + \sum\limits_{k =  - 1}^n {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k + 1}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\k\end{array}} \right)}  = 0 - 0 = 0$$
which completes the proof.
Note that we have used
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}n\\{n + 1}\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
n\\{ - 1}\end{array}} \right) = 0$$
which are the direct consequences of the identity $\frac{1}{(-1)!}=0$